# Buffering in WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator 3857 using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3, buffer

I have read all the buffer issues topics but haven't found solution to my problem.

I have two layers:

1. Border layer of Tokyo ward - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator 3857
2. A CSV text layer with x,y coordinates of buildings which I saved in the same CRS.

Now, I need to buffer one (central) point from the point layer on the scale of the whole Tokyo to make some calculations. But when I add buffer and set the distance (cca 14 km) buffer actually has the distance of cca 11km.

[image]

I tried re-saving and opening the point layer, re-doing the layer couple of time. Followed all the instructions on other similar questions. But the same problem occurs. I have done the same on couple of cities more and there was no problem in making the buffer correctly.

Any other inputs?

Comment: Web Mercator is absolutely wrong on distance calculations, and shouldn't ever be trusted for them, especially in high latitudes.

Comment: The ArcGIS Help has a nice topic about this issue and the difference between a geodesic and euclidian buffer, see this: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/how-buffer-analysis-works.htm

Comment: Thank you guys, all the other layer came in the right projection so I could make correct buffers and I assumed this one will work here.

Answer (score 4):

As [@Vince already stated in comments](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/331627/qgis-buffer-issue-again#comment541151_331627), Web Mercator is not suitable for this.

Reproject your layers (Save as...) to a local metric one. Regarding epsg.io this could be [UTM Zone 54N (EPSG:3095)](https://epsg.io/3095) for example.

Comment: Not to criticize - just an information - EPSG 3095 was defined for old Tokyo datum (on Bessel ellipsoid) and replaced by current EPSG 3100 (on JGD2000 - ITRF94).